# spnavcfg - SpaceNavigator in Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux

Attempting to install my SpaceNavigator on arch linux using the open source spacenavd service. The service starts up fine, and I have the libspacenav and spacenavd packages installed. I am attempting to build spnavcfg from the sourceforge website.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/spacenav/files/

I downloaded libspacenav and spacenavd from the AUR, ran makepkg -s, and then sudo pacman -U and installed the packages locally, no issues.

spacenavcfg is another story, will probably have to build my own ABS package before I can use pacman on it, however when I extract the contents from sourceforge, it does not compile. I can successfully run sudo ./configure, but when I type 'make', I get the following error:

```
gcc -o spnavcfg spnavcfg.o front.o back.o cfgfile.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
/usr/bin/ld: front.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XOpenDisplay'
/usr/lib/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'spnavcfg' failed
make: *** [spnavcfg] Error 1
```

I have not been able to figure out what the issue is, the usual google/forum trolling has not yielded any answers.

Thanks!
Barrett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this AUR PKGBUILD this time: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spnavcfg/